# How do I prevent Google Chrome from requesting the same image multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, chat

I currently have a project I'm working on that consists of a chat with multiple features. As users talk in the chat, data is appended to a chat-view `<div>` via Javascript like so:

```
document.getElementById("chatview").innerHTML += "Chat message layout and content here.";
```

When users edit old messages, I use an icon to display that the message has been modified in the past. Whenever a new string is appended to the HTML of the chat-view `<div>`, all the `<img>` are reloaded and requested from the server, even though all the images are pointing to the same URL.

How can I prevent this unneeded bandwidth?

Comment: use jquery/ajax to perform an asynchronous load. This will load specified data instead of the entire page

Comment: are you sure it doesn't say "from cache" on the repeat pulls? or if you have cache disabled...

Comment: Not from cache, and Chrome indicates that the network data transfered increases with each new chat message.

Comment: And asynchronous load to what?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something wrong with the HTTP headers being sent from your server. Make sure it is cacheable and not loaded from HTTPS.

Comment: No, that's not it. All content is hosted via HTTPS and Chrome says the URL is https://*.

Comment: Since browsers don't cache HTTPS, that might be why. Try it with CSS spirits to see if it helps.